# Prove $\overline E = E \cup \{p\}$, and that $\overline E$ is compact

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $\{p_n\}$be a sequence in $X$ for $(X,d)$ usual metric, and assume that $p_n \to p$. Let $E=\{p_n :n∈ \mathbb N\}$ denote the range of $\{p_n\}$. Prove $\overline E = E \cup \{p\}$, and that $\overline E$ is compact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT 1 : A point $x$ of the closure has a sequence of the set $E$ converging to it. Prove that there will be a subsequence of $p_n$ converging to $x$.

HINT 2 : Take an open cover of the set. Some element of the cover will have to contain $p$. But this will imply that this element of the cover takes care of all elements of the set $E$, except for finitely many. Take care of the rest with finitely many other open sets.